# Get value in template of ManyToMany ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I need to display the values of the **categories field** from the **class Analiza** from the models below in a template.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Analiza(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = "Категорија")
    ...
```

How do I do that? I've been reading documentation, but no reference to a situation of this kind (ManyToMany of ForeignKey).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an instance of class Analiza, it will have a `categories` many-to-many field manager attribute that you can reference in your template:

```
<ul>
{% for category in obj.categories.all %}
    <li>{{ category }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or whatever - the point is that it'll be an iterable returning instances of Category.